# mime decode pdf quoted-printable

Tags: php, encoding, mime, mime-message

I've been building a simple ticket system and it's all done and working except for when it receives PDF files via email that have been sent using `quoted-printable` encoding. I've tried using `quoted_printable_decode()`, the `quoted-printable.decode` stream filter, the later just created an empty file. I've also tried using `$input = preg_replace('/=([a-f0-9]{2})/ie', "chr(hexdec('\\1'))", $input)`.

However the PDF file is always unreadable. I've compared the original with the rebuilt version and there are a lot of `00` missing and some other characters replaced.

[original file](http://ian-barker.co.uk/pdf-example/svn-book.pdf)

[rebuilt file](http://ian-barker.co.uk/pdf-example/svn-book-rebuilt.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by using `quoted_printable_decode()` on each line rather than the whole mime-part